# On the normal mixture $X\sim\mathcal N(NY,NY(1-Y))$, $Y\sim\operatorname{Beta}(\alpha,\beta)$

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, moment-generating-functions

Suppose I generate a random variable by first selecting from $Y \sim \operatorname{Beta}(\alpha, \beta)$

I then use the result to generate a random variable distributed as $X \sim \operatorname{Normal}(NY,NY(1-Y))$ for some fixed $N$.

Clearly $X$ is a mixture of normals, but is $X$ itself a normal distribution, or any other well known distribution?

---

Below is an attempt using MGF as per comment suggestion.

We have: $M_x = E_Y[M_{x|y}]$

Now $$M_{x|y}(t) = \exp(Ny t + \frac{1}{2}Ny(1-y) t^2) = \exp(Nyt(1 + \frac{(1-y)t}{2}))$$

Now presumably $$E_Y[M_{x|y}] = \int_{0}^{1} M_{x|y} f(y)dy = \int_{0}^{1} exp(Nyt(1 + \frac{(1-y)t}{2})) \frac{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)} y^{\alpha-1}(1-y)^{\beta-1}dy$$

Now the moment generating function of the beta distribution is given by,

$$M_b(t,\alpha,\beta) = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta))}\int_{0}^{1}e^{ty}y^{\alpha-1}(1-y)^{\beta-1}dy$$

Thus,

$$M_b(Nt(1 + \frac{t}{2}),\alpha,\beta) = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta))}\int_{0}^{1}e^{Nt(1 + \frac{t}{2})y}y^{\alpha-1}(1-y)^{\beta-1}dy$$

Comment: Try to use Moment Generating Function for the normal  r.v. $X$ (given $Y$).

Comment: @StasVolkov, I've done that now above, but not sure what to do next?

Comment: alas, I do not think it can be simplified much further...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Clearly $X$ is a mixture of normals, but is $X$ itself a normal distribution, or any other well known distribution?

As you have already pointed out $X$ cannot be normal as it is a normal mixture; however, conditioning $X$ on $Y$ does give a normally distributed random variable since
$$
X|Y\sim\mathcal N(nY,nY(1-y)).
$$

The random variable $X$ is an example of a [normal location-scale mixture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_probability_distribution#Examples). The Wikipedia article in the link gives some examples of well-known examples of this type of mixture model; however, none of the given examples match your specific model.

As for the moments of $X$ note that since $X|Y\sim\mathcal N(nY,nY(1-y))$ we can write the moments of $X$ as
$$
\mathsf EX^k=\mathsf E(\mathsf E(X^k|Y)).
$$
Using equation (18) in this [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2301.08790.pdf) article allows us to write this expression as
$$
\mathsf EX^k=\mathsf E\left(\left(\frac{i\sqrt{nY(1-Y)}}{\sqrt 2}\right)^kH_k\left(-i\frac{nY}{\sqrt{2nY(1-Y)}}\right)\right),
$$
where the expectation is taken w.r.t. $Y\sim\operatorname{Beta}(\alpha,\beta)$. Using the [explicit expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Explicit_expression) for the Hermite polynomial this becomes
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathsf EX^k
&=\mathsf E\left(\left(\frac{i\sqrt{nY(1-Y)}}{\sqrt 2}\right)^kk!\sum_{\ell=0}^{\lfloor k/2\rfloor}\frac{(-1)^\ell}{\ell!(k-2\ell)!}2^{k-2\ell}\left(-i\frac{nY}{\sqrt{2nY(1-Y)}}\right)^{k-2\ell}\right)\\
&=k!\sum_{\ell=0}^{\lfloor k/2\rfloor}\frac{2^{-\ell}n^{k-\ell}}{\ell!(k-2\ell)!}
\mathsf E\left(Y^{k-\ell}(1-Y)^\ell\right)\\
&=k!\sum_{\ell=0}^{\lfloor k/2\rfloor}\frac{2^{-\ell}n^{k-\ell}}{\ell!(k-2\ell)!}
\mathsf E\left(Y^{k-\ell}(1-Y)^\ell\right).
\end{aligned}
$$
Knowing the moments of the beta distribution we obtain the final result
$$
\mathsf EX^k
=k!\sum_{\ell=0}^{\lfloor k/2\rfloor}\frac{2^{-\ell}n^{k-\ell}}{\ell!(k-2\ell)!}
\frac{\operatorname B(\alpha+k-\ell,\beta+\ell)}{\operatorname B(\alpha,\beta)},
$$
which may (possibly) be written in terms of hypergeometric functions.

The analytical expression for the moments can be implemented in Mathematica as

```
EX[k_] := 
  k! Sum[(2^-l n^(k - l))/(l! (k - 2 l)!)
      Beta[\[Alpha] + k - l, \[Beta] + l]/Beta[\[Alpha], \[Beta]], {l,
      0, Floor[k/2]}];
Table[{k, FullSimplify[FunctionExpand[EX[k]]]}, {k, 0, 3}];
TeXForm[%]
```

Here is a table of the first several

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 k & \mathsf EX^k \\
 0 & 1 \\
 1 & \frac{\alpha  n}{\alpha +\beta } \\
 2 & \frac{\alpha  n (\beta +\alpha  n+n)}{(\alpha +\beta )
   (\alpha +\beta +1)} \\
 3 & \frac{\alpha  (\alpha +1) n^2 (3 \beta +(\alpha +2)
   n)}{(\alpha +\beta ) (\alpha +\beta +1) (\alpha +\beta +2)}
   \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$